# Snowflake - How to Call Stored Procedure with Date range and Boolean parameter

Tags: stored-procedures

A Stored procedure was created in our Snowflake environment, and I need to call this stored procedure in SSRS to convert the report.

In SSRS

```
EXEC <Stored Procedure Name> @StartDate, @EndDate, @Include_Consult, @Include_Interval
```

In Snowflake (based on my search). Note: i'm using SET syntax to provide the variable values. I'm getting Error: Bind variable :STARTDATE not set. (line 11) when executing.

```
CALL CDW_PRD_CALL_DB.CDW_CONTACTCENTER_RPT_SC.USP_REPORTS_CCP_KVPMAP_INTERVAL(:STARTDATE,:ENDDATE,:INCLUDE_CONSULTS,:INTERVAL_DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake you refer to variables that you've previously set using a $ prefix e.g.

```
CALL USP_REPORTS_CCP_KVPMAP_INTERVAL(
     $STARTDATE,
     $ENDDATE,
     $INCLUDE_CONSULTS,
     $INTERVAL_DATE);
```